Meaning of Hisoka's hand gesture (other than that from chapter 326)
The infamous Hisoka's hand gesture in chapter 326 of the manga (during Chairman Election arc) is well documented; see here, for example.
There is another hand gesture from Hisoka that caught my attention: it occurs at chapter 47 of the manga, during his first encounter with Gon and Killua at the Heavens Arena:

I don't intend to ask about every hand gesture from Hisoka; I am asking in this case because I feel that this specific gesture genuinely means something.
